# Print out inner series

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [139]: pandas.__version__
Out[139]: '0.7.3'
```

I have two aligned series in a `DataFrame` which have several unmatched "NaN". I would like to print the intersection between them removing all "NaN's", but without loose alignment. That is, I want to remove the rows from both series whem I find a "NaN" in one of them. It sounds simple, but I not doing any operation between the series to dropna's afterwards and cannot dropna's from the series separately. I couldn't figure out the right df function to do this - several are not documented.
Just an example, I want to take this:

```
10         NaN     -1.200
11         NaN     -1.324
12    0.000585        NaN
13    0.000573     -1.453
14         NaN     -2.006
```

and print this:

```
13    0.000573     -1.453
```

Comment: This is a little hard to follow. Why isn't df.dropna() what you want? Have you tried that on the above DataFrame?

Comment: You mean dropna the df entirely??? It might have a better way.   That's a very large dataset.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what you want to do? What are you describing if not that? You can also specify specific column subsets using the `subset` parameter: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna

Comment: newdf =  df1.dropna()[['S', 'JEXP']]

Comment: Do you mean you want to drop rows where there are NaNs in either of the S or JEXP columns only? (I'm trying to help here; please be clear, or I can't!) Try `newdf = df1.dropna(subset=['S', 'JEXP'])`

Comment: Yep, that's what I wrote in my post. My last comment has solved the problem and your suggestion either. thanks for helping.

Comment: Please enter your solution as an answer and accept it, so this will no longer stand out as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comments above, the best answer is:

```
newdf = df1.dropna()[['S', 'JEXP']]
```

that dropan's from a slice of the original df, keeping just the series of interest. 
Karmel has suggested:

```
newdf = df1.dropna(subset=['S', 'JEXP'])
```

which also works and dropan's based on the subset list, however, keeping all others series - it duplicates your dataset.